# How to get a per-user count of running processes using Command or PowerShell on a Windows Remote Desktop Session Host?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

Is it possible to get a per-user count of running processes on a Windows Remote Desktop Session Host using Command or PowerShell? I want to target users that have a running process count higher than X and perform subsequent actions based on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with Powershell easily.
First you need to get all processes on RDS host excluding system ones (for an example I exclude NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM, you may want more).
Then check unique users and count running processes for each.

```
$pr = Get-Process -IncludeUserName | sort username | where {$_.username -ne "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"}
$users = $pr.Username | Get-Unique
foreach ($user in $users) {
   $count = (Get-Process -IncludeUserName | where {$_.username -eq $user}).count
   if ($count -gt 50) {"User $user has $count processes running"}
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This helps a great deal - thank you! Further to this, how would I display a list of all users with more than 50 processes running?

```
$pr = Get-Process -IncludeUserName | sort username | where {$_.username -match "domain"}
$users = $pr.Username | Get-Unique
foreach ($user in $users) {
   if ((Get-Process -IncludeUserName | where {$_.username -eq $user}).count -gt 50){
      $uname = $user.substring(6)
      write-host $uname + <count>
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a complete noob and can't figure out how to format a block of code

Comment: @Levi you overcomplicate things. I will update my code with one more line to output users with more than 50 processes

Comment: After a ton of research and the head start from @Hardoman, I ended up with this very quick one-liner that works very well:
`Get-Process -IncludeUserName | Group-Object -Property username | Select-Object -Property Name,Count | where-object {($_.Name -match "DOMAIN") -and ($_.Name -ne "DOMAIN\adminusername") -and ($_.Count -gt 50)}`